# Get count of variable based on another variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm currently building a rapheal.js map based on some json data that I'm exporting from my DB in wordpress.  I've had some help on building the JSON, but I'm having trouble with a few elements I need to count up.

If you look at my script below you will notice 2 rows that are **gender** and **country**.  The gender row can be either male, female, or other.  The country is obviously country.  What I'm trying to do is count up how many per gender are in each country and then display it in the tooltip array HTML.  This means that it needs to first check the country and then check how many of each gender belong to that country.

```
function mapInfo() {

  global $wpdb;

  $preJSON = array();

  // select only columns you need
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_mas";


  //$count = 0; // this is for $preJSON[] index

  foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {


      $value = $row->id;
      $latitude = $row->lat;
      $longitude = $row->long;
      $gender = $row->gender;
      $country = $row->country_srt;
      $tooltip = array(
          "content" => '<h2 class="country-name">- '. $country .' -</h2><p>female amount, male amount, other amount'
      );
      $main = array(
          "latitude" => $latitude,
          "longitude" => $longitude,
          "tooltip" => $tooltip
      );


      $preJSON[$country.$count] = array(
          "latitude" => $latitude,
          "longitude" => $longitude,
          "tooltip" => $tooltip
      );


      ++$count;
  }
  wp_send_json($preJSON);
}
```

I think I can do this with a SQL script, but I'd hate to hit the database two times.

Comment: I think I can solve this with **REPEAT** and a few sub queries, could you give me a copy of your table design?

Comment: What do you use `$main` for? And what do you use `$value` for?

Comment: ps. Don't comment `$count = 0;`. That will give you a warning when doing `++` while `$count` isn't initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I think it is impossible to accomplish this task in the same loop you are using, because it will mess around with the logic of the loop. Basically, you try processing all the result rows while you process only one (the current) row. So I didn't even bother to look at this possibility.

Instead, in sql, using only one query it is quite feasible. I don't now what data exactly have you in the database, but I assumed it is something like this.

```
 id   lat    lng      gen  country   

  1     1       2      f    USA                  
  2     2       2      f    USA                  
  3     3       2      o    FRA                  
  5     4       3      m    FRA                  
  7     5       5      m    USA                  
  9     1       2      f    USA                  
 10     2       2      o    USA                  
 11     3       2      m    FRA                  
 12     4       3      f    FRA                  
 13     5       5      o    USA                  
 15     3       2      m    FRA                  
 16     4       3      f    FRA                  
 17     5       5      m    USA
```

This query will take the table as it is, and will left join consecutively the total count of rows with fem, mal and oth for each row matching the country.

```
   SELECT 
    w.id as 'id', 
    w.lat as lat, 
    w.lng as lng, 
    w.gen as gen, 
    w.country as cntry, 
    c.count1 as cnt_fem, 
    c.count2 as cnt_mal, 
    c.count3 as cnt_oth
 FROM wp_mas as w
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        wp_mas.country as cntry1, 
        wp_mas.gen as gen1, 
        COUNT(case wp_mas.gen when 'Female' then 1 else NULL end) as count1, 
        COUNT(case wp_mas.gen when 'Male' then 1 else NULL end) as count2, 
        COUNT(case wp_mas.gen when 'Other' then 1 else NULL end) as count3
    FROM 
        wp_mas
    GROUP BY cntry1) 
 as c
 ON w.country=c.cntry1
```

Maybe, the query isn't very elegant, but it works. The result will be:

```
 id   lat    lng      gen     cntry     cnt_fem    cnt_mal    cnt_oth 

  1     1      2      f       USA             3          2          2 
  2     2      2      f       USA             3          2          2 
  3     3      2      o       FRA             2          3          1 
  5     4      3      m       FRA             2          3          1 
  7     5      5      m       USA             3          2          2 
  9     1      2      f       USA             3          2          2 
 10     2      2      o       USA             3          2          2 
 11     3      2      m       FRA             2          3          1 
 12     4      3      f       FRA             2          3          1 
 13     5      5      o       USA             3          2          2 
 15     3      2      m       FRA             2          3          1 
 16     4      3      f       FRA             2          3          1 
 17     5      5      m       USA             3          2          2
```

Each row will contains 3 columns with the total count of female, males and others matching the country in this row. So now you can use the same loop you are using:

```
  foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {


      $value = $row->id;
      $latitude = $row->lat;
      $longitude = $row->lng;
      $gender = $row->gen;
      $country = $row->cntry;
      $cnt_fem = $row->cnt_fem;
      $cnt_mal = $row->cnt_mal;
      $cnt_oth = $row->cnt_oth;
      $tooltip = array(
          "content" => '<h2 class="country-name">- '. $country .' -</h2><p>'.$cnt_fem.' females, '.$cnt_mal.' males, '.$cnt_oth.' other'
      );


      $preJSON[$country.$count] = array(
          "latitude" => $latitude,
          "longitude" => $longitude,
          "tooltip" => $tooltip
      );


      ++$count;
  }
  wp_send_json($preJSON);
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm getting an empty array.  My table is as you described however the gender column has Male, Female, and Other instead of m, f, o as you described.  I adjusted the SQL accordingly but it doesnt seem to output anything.  Wondering if there is an issue with negative values in my longitude.

Comment: I've just noticed that your table name is "wp_mas" but in my case I've used "wp_maps". I have updated the sql query. Check to see if that was the problem.  Also, I have used aliases for column names, so the indexes of the array are slightly different from yours. Double check that as well in your foreach loop.

Comment: I actually already had updated it in my dev environment before hand.  So not sure what is causing the issue.  When I just print out the row I get nothing.  If you read in previous comments I was having trouble with accessing the long table column because of the negative values and only had access to it when i did a select all.  Wondering if this is the issue happening here.

Comment: maybe the conflict appears because "long" is also a data type, try escaping it in the query or change the column name to something else, "lng" for example.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.  I'll give it a shot

Comment: That was totally the reason!  The only odd thing is that in some random cases the a count isnt added to entrys that only have 1 gender in them.  As soon as I add another gender to that country it will display two in the output.  Not sure why it is only affecting a few of the single entrys

Comment: Upon further inspection it is only happening for countries with 1 gender that is Male or Other.  If the country has only 1 gender that is female it works great and shows up as 1.  In fact now that I check again, no records will show up unless there is 1 female present for the country.  There can be records with 5 Males and 6 others but nothing will show until i add 1 female.

Comment: I had redesigned my query to overcome the problem. I didn't think that your countries do not have females in it, lol :). Actually I overlooked this issue. check if it works now

Answer (score 0):

Using the GROUP sql you should be able to get what you're looking for.

```
group by gender, country
```

This changes the result set into a grouping one of each group.

```
select count(*) as num_of_matches, gender, country, group_concat("id") as ids from wp_mas group by gender, country
```

will give you something like

```
3, "male", "canada", "4,6,7"
```

which you can then explode on the "ids" for a list if ids.

```
$ids = explode($row->ids, ",")
```

Comment: I was hoping to not have to use another SQL hit and keep it all in php.  Since im selecting ALL with count do i still have access to everything else I did before in my original SQL request?

Comment: Sort of a compromise to deal with a result set from the SQL database that's grouped accoordingly. Maybe something like `select * from wp_mas where id in (select group_concat("id") as ids from wp_mas group by gender, country))`. Not sure if this works but the concept should be there.

Comment: I see.  Was hoping there would be a way to just loop inside the original statement via PHP and and set up the genders with the data I already have returned.  I'm not really great with more robust SQL commands and not sure how to chain them inside the code i've already written above.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code to reuse same $sql to get number of different genders per country. You should try this and see if it works.

```
$all_countries=array();
foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $key => $row ) {
    $value = $row->id;
    $latitude = $row->lat;
    $longitude = $row->long;
    $gender = $row->gender;
    $country = $row->country_srt;
    if(!isset($all_countries[$country][$gender])) $all_countries[$country][$gender] = array();
    array_push($all_countries[$country][$gender],array("value"=>$value,"latitude"=>$latitude,"longitude"=>$longitude));
}

$main=array();
foreach($all_countries as $country => $data){
    $tooltip = array("content" => '<h2 class="country-name">- '. $country .' -</h2><p>'.count($data['female']).', '.count($data['male']).', '.count($data['other']).'</p>');
    $gender='';
    if(count($data['male'])>0) $gender='male'; else if(count($data['female'])>0) $gender='female'; else $gender='other';
    array_push($main,array(
                                "latitude" => $data[$gender][0]['latitude'],
                                "longitude" => $data[$gender][0]['longitude'],
                                "tooltip" => $tooltip
                            ));
}
// Now you can do whatever you want with $main. echo its content as JSON or return, its upto you
```

$main is the final array you need. Do whatever you want with it.

Comment: uhh... no. your second foreach needs another foreach in it. also you are not setting $latitude, etc that you are array_pushing. So all pushed elements will be the last element of the first foreach

Comment: I made a mistake at second foreach, I corrected it in my answer now. Thanks to you @nl-x.

Comment: This just leaves me with all nulls in the final array `{
"value": null,
"latitude": null,
"longitude": null,
"tooltip": {
"content": "<h2 class=\"country-name\">- USA -</h2><p>0, 0, 0</p>"
}
},`

Comment: @Mr.BigglesWorth I had last edited and tested the code 50 mins ago, perhaps you tried the older code. Please make sure if the code you tried is same.

Comment: One more thing to check is, if the gender you have on database is either "male", "female" or "other". Your output of `0, 0, 0` seems quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is traverse the result from your query twice. You don't need to call your query twice, though. Just reference the result to a variable first.

Then foreach the result a first time just to do the counting. And later do your original foreach, and use the counted values in your tooltip.

As you can see below, I did the counting in a separate array that holds the count for each country/gender combination.

```
// select only columns you need
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_mas";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
$count = 0;
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    if (!isset($count[$row->gender][$row->country_srt])) {
        $counters[$row->gender][$row->country_srt] = 0;
    }
    $counters[$row->gender][$row->country_srt] ++;
}
foreach( $result as $key => $row ) {
    $value = $row->id;
    $latitude = $row->lat;
    $longitude = $row->long;
    $gender = $row->gender;
    $country = $row->country_srt;
    $females = $counters['female'][$country];
    $males = $counters['male'][$country];
    $others = $counters['other'][$country];
    $tooltip = array(
        "content" => "<h2 class='country-name'>- $country -</h2><p>female $females, male $males, other $others"
    );
    $main = array(
        "latitude" => $latitude,
        "longitude" => $longitude,
        "tooltip" => $tooltip
    );
    $preJSON[$country . $count] = array(
        "latitude" => $latitude,
        "longitude" => $longitude,
        "tooltip" => $tooltip
    );
    ++$count;
}
wp_send_json($preJSON);
```

But you can compact this code by leaving away the unused variables and doing references inline:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_mas"; // select only columns you need
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
$count = 0;
foreach( $result as $row )
    $counters[$row->gender][$row->country_srt] = isset($counters[$row->gender][$row->country_srt]) ? $counters[$row->gender][$row->country_srt] + 1 : 1;
foreach( $result as $key => $row )
    $preJSON[$row->country_srt . ++$count] = array(
        "latitude" => $row->lat,
        "longitude" => $row->long,
        "tooltip" => array(
            "content" => "<h2 class='country-name'>- {$row->country_srt} -</h2><p>female {$counters['female'][$row->country_srt]}, male {$counters['male'][$row->country_srt]}, other {$counters['other'][$row->country_srt]}"
        )
    );
wp_send_json($preJSON);
```

Comment: This leaves me with blank on all male, female, and others.   I'm left with `"USA1": {
"latitude": "41.94660000",
"longitude": "-87.74660000",
"tooltip": {
"content": "<h2 class='country-name'>- USA -</h2><p>female , male , other "
}
}`

Comment: I misspelled `$row->country_srt` in the compacted code. I fixed that now. Are you sure on the spelling of the genders? Should they not start with a capital letter?